# How to add admin tools / services as startup in windows

Tags: windows

How can I add those services in administrative tools services in windows desktop as shortcuts so I can start/stop services easily. Any idea anyone?

Comment: Do you want to create a desktop shortcut to the `Services` (gear icon) MMC?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can create a batch file with one of the following:

Net start service-name

or

Net stop service-name

To start and stop services respectively. To get the name, go into the console and double click on a service. The name you need is listed as "Service Name".

You can also rapidly get to the services management console by going to Start -> Run and typing "Services.msc"

Really, though, why are you messing with services so often? They should be fire and forget.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are asking for is an MMC console with a boatload of snapins in it.

Launch mmc.exe

Click file > Add/Remove Snap-in

Add whatever snap-ins you want. The one that controls services is names Services. You can also add anything from RSAT or any other admin consoles.

Save the MMC and put it on your desktop or wherever else you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Right click your desktop, select "New" --> "Shortcut"

[image]

Enter `services.msc` in the location field. Click "Next", then "Finish"

[image]

*Voilà*. A desktop shortcut to `services.msc`

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Initially I thought that the OP wanted to make a shortcut with services.msc and other admin tools. After rereading it, it seems like this might be what he actually wants.

Comment: @MarkM I +1'd yours as well as I am not clear on what OP is asking.  I will gladly delete this answer should it not meet their needs.